# Why does System.Environment.Version report framework 2?

Tags: asp.net

In a web site targeted for Framework 3.5, on a machine with up to 3.5 SP 1 installed, when I call System.Environment.Version in a page, it reports 2.0.50727.3053.  Can anyone suggest why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MSDN docs for Environment.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) say this:

Gets a Version object that describes the major, minor, build, and revision numbers of the common language runtime.

The CLR version in 3.5 SP1 is still 2.0.

Hence, no error, it behaves exactly as documented.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't say 'no error' - I'd say 'howling, screaming cock-up' - but that's on MS's part, no the OP's...  :-)

Comment: I don't know... If they'd called this property "FrameworkVersion" and then returned the CLR version I'd be pissed - but as it is now the name is OK (though a bit generic) and the docs are clear. They could conceivably add a clarification ("This is NOT the framework version!"), but still.

Comment: It's not the name or the value of the property I object to, it's particularly the 3.5->3.5SP1->3.5SP1GDR progression which seems so badly handled.

Answer (score 7):

It is telling you the CLR version, which is still 2.0x; it jumps to 4.0x in .NET 4.0 - but until then, all of .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 share a CLR version (give-or-take the small numbers ;-p)

Answer (score 2):

Because the underlying CLR for .NET framework 3.5 is still 2.0.50727.3053.

.NET 3.0 and 3.5 are additions to .NET 2.0 - the underlying CLR is still the same.

This will change with .NET 4.0 with a new CLR 4.0.

Marc