# Why .NET version is different for two app with same target framework version

Tags: c#, .net, windows, environment-variables

Added small code to find .NET version at runtime in:

1. sample program
2. proprietary app.

   ```
           var version = Environment.Version;
           Console.WriteLine(version.ToString());
   ```

Both were compiled with target version .NET Framework 4.

Sample prog output is **4.0.30319.255**

proprietary app output is **2.0.50727.8000**

Sample prog is being compiled and run on same machine.

This proprietary app is getting compiled on one build machine and deployed on other production machine.

Why this difference of version is there.

Where should I look for this issue in proprietary app . Give me some pointers.

Comment: is that work for you

Comment: I'd suspect the build process on your build machine ignores the target framework 4 specified in the project file and uses 3.5 instead. This may be due to the MSBuild version and its target framework.

Answer (score 1):

First Check documentation:

> **Environment.Version Property**
>
> Gets a Version object that describes the major, minor, build, and
> revision numbers of the common language runtime.

**Caution**

> For the .NET Framework 4.5 later, we do not recommend using the
> Version property to detect the version of the runtime; instead, you
> can determine the version of the common language runtime by querying
> the registry. For more information, see [How to: Determine Which .NET
> Framework Versions Are Installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx).

Refer below link for more clarification about your question:
[How do I detect at runtime that .NET version 4.5 is currently running your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517159/how-to-detect-at-runtime-that-net-version-4-5-currently-running-your-code)

> With 2.0 vs. 3.0 or 3.5 Environment.Version was of no help since it
> always returned 2.0 as all those framework versions were using the CLR
> 2.0.

Read it too: [NET Versioning and Multi-Targeting - .NET 4.5 is an in-place upgrade to .NET 4.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx)

> Note that this in-place replacement is very different from the side by
> side installs of .NET 2.0 and 3.0/3.5 which all ran on the 2.0 version
> of the CLR. The two 3.x versions were basically library enhancements
> on top of the core .NET 2.0 runtime. Both versions ran under the .NET
> 2.0 runtime which wasn’t changed (other than for security patches and bug fixes) for the whole 3.x cycle. The 4.5 update instead completely
> replaces the .NET 4.0 runtime and leaves the actual version number set
> at v4.0.30319

**References:**
[Why does System.Environment.Version report framework 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708747/why-does-system-environment-version-report-framework-2)

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.Version` gives you the version of CLR use, not the .Net framework itself

See [How do I detect at runtime that .NET version 4.5 is currently running your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517159/how-to-detect-at-runtime-that-net-version-4-5-currently-running-your-code)

Comment: Eric I need to detect version for code compiled for .NET version 4 and .NET version 2

Comment: @VikramSingh Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time